# Find URL of Flash radio stream

Tags: streaming, flash, url, firebug

I'm trying to use Firebug to get the stream URL of this site, so I can play it using VLC.  Does anyone know how to?  Thanks.

http://www.magic983.com/listen/

Comment: I installed "Adblock Plus" to eliminate a lot of the ads so it would be easier to go through.  Then, in Firebug, I looked under the "Net" section and then under "Flash", but none of those seem to be it.

Answer (score 4):

I encourage you to use their website, as you probably get the service for free thanks to their adverts.

However, for educational purposes, you can use the browser's built-in network analyzer (I use Google Chrome) or wireshark to get the URL:

http://8303.live.streamtheworld.com/WKXWFMAAC

A full list of URL's can be found in the xml file:

http://playerservices.streamtheworld.com/api/livestream?version=1.5&mount=WKXWFMAAC&lang=EN&transports=http&nobuf=1355525218692

Anyhow, my VLC doesn't seem to connect whilst Totem works perfectly fine, and I can download the stream as well.

For a more detailed answer, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814493/audio-streaming-protocol-for-streamtheworld-net

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Great first post! :)